# How to create and use Pipelines via Java API in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, java

I'm trying to create a timestamp to attach to any documents that are indexed. I know this is possible in Query DSL via the below set of commands. I cannot find out how to do so through the Java API. Have any of you done this before?

Thanks!

```
DELETE anindex


PUT _ingest/pipeline/timestamp {
    "description" : "describe pipeline",
    "processors" : [{
                      "set" : {
                                "field": "timestamp",
                                "value": "{{_ingest.timestamp}}"
                              }
                    }]
               }


PUT anindex
{
   "mappings": {
                 "jeff": {
                         }
               }
}


PUT anindex/jeff/id10?pipeline=timestamp
{
  "hi": "jeff"
}


GET anindex/jeff/id10
```

Comment: As per my understanding, you have already define your Ingest Pipeline "timestamp". Now, you only need JAVA API to Index documents by passing it through "timestamp" Pipeline everytime. Right?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Not quite. We would like to translate the entirety of that code into java. Including the definition of the pipeline.

Comment: But why do you require to define the pipeline definition everytime?
It is a kind of meta information or mapping which needs to be define once and prior to data insertion or manipulation.

Comment: You're right, I'd define and call it once, but the code to create a pipeline has to be in Java.

Comment: I have update my answer. Hope that helps

Comment: It does. Thank you very much Hatim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Java API in 6.2.4 supports adding .setPipeline to the prepareIndex method. Here is an example:

```
bulkRequest.add(client.prepareIndex(Main.config.getProperty("index"), 
   "data", entry.getId()).setSource(jsonInString).setPipeline("opennlp-pipeline"));
```

Comment: Finally! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Elasticsearch doesn't have JAVA API for defining Ingest Pipeline.
As a work around, you can do the following to define Ingest pipeline from JAVA using HttpURLConnection:

```
URL obj = new URL("http://localhost:9200/_ingest/pipeline/timestamp");
String json = "{\n" + 
        "  \"description\": \"describe pipeline\",\n" + 
        "  \"processors\": [\n" + 
        "    {\n" + 
        "      \"set\": {\n" + 
        "        \"field\": \"timestamp\",\n" + 
        "        \"value\": \"{{_ingest.timestamp}}\"\n" + 
        "      }\n" + 
        "    }\n" + 
        "  ]\n" + 
        "}";
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

con.setRequestMethod("PUT");
con.setDoInput(true);
con.setDoOutput(true);
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
osw.write(json);
osw.flush();
osw.close();

System.out.println(con.getResponseCode() + " : " + con.getResponseMessage());
if (con != null)
    con.disconnect();
```

And now, below is the Java code for Indexing document by passing them through created "timestamp" Ingest pipeline:

```
TransportClient client = buildTransPortClient();

Map<String, Object> object = new HashMap<String, Object>();
object.put("user","kimchy");
object.put("postDate",new Date());
object.put("message","trying out Elasticsearch");

IndexResponse response = client.prepareIndex("test", "test", "100")
        .setSource(object)
        .setPipeline("timestamp")
        .get();

System.out.println(response);
```